# Newsletter form on mobile device

Tags: forms, mobile, buttons, newsletter

I am thinking about the best way to display a newsletter form on mobile device.

1st solution : a button. Then, a modal window appears on click with the form
[image]

2nd solution : the form is displaying directly on the page :
[image]

What do you suggest ? Which solution is better ? Do you have better solution ?

Comment: Is there any user registration in this app?

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: The second one requires one click less and tells the user that the only needed information is his email.

Comment: I think second option would be good and would accomplish the task with less effort.

Answer (score 5):

Choose second option; it helps you avoid additional click.

To get users signed-up for your newsletter - **you need to give them the reason to take efforts** and provide information. Also, tell them about **the benefits of signing up**:

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your solutions are quite understood. Therefore I would suggest selecting the one solution that requires fewer steps:

*1st solution*

(3 steps) Get newsletter - Write email address - Press button

*2nd solution*

(2 steps) Write email address - Press button

Therefore, I would go **for the 2nd solution.**

Also, have a look at this article about how to use modals in mobile. It has some interesting thoughts, on where to user modals:

> Interruption: Forcing the user to make a decision or complete a task
>   at an important part of their workflow. Ask yourself, “do I really
>   want to interrupt the user?”
>
> Feedback or Correction: Confirming
>   decisions. E.g., “are you sure?” moment.
>
> Deep Dive: Focusing the user
>   on a single piece of content, be it an image, article, or a video.

http://uxmag.com/articles/modals-on-mobile-how-to-use-them-wisely

Answer (score 0):

Always go for the option that requires the least number of clicks. In your case, that would be the 2nd one. Keep the Subscribe button disabled until the correct format for email is entered to avoid accidental/unnecessary clicks